# hr vertical centered in a div

Tags: html, css, css-position

How to center a HR tag vertically in a div, i tried this but its not centered perfectly

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 80vw;
    height: 40vh;
    border: solid 4px #333;
}

hr {
    height: 5px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `transform` to `translateY(-50%);` and add `margin: 0;` to the `hr`:

(BTW: No need for `top` *and*  `bottom` settings if you have a defined `height`, having one of those is sufficient)

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 80vw;
    height: 40vh;
    border: solid 4px #333;
}

hr {
    height: 5px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the same method I use for perfectly centered elements. Using `top:50%;` with transform: `translateY(-50%);` will automatically calculate the perfect vertical center. Using height is not even really necessary but good practice to prevent CLS which will appease our Lord Google Bot. If you don't know the height of the element or it changes dynamically, this method will work best.

Comment: @CChoma `height` determines the thickness of the `hr` in this case

Answer (score 3):

The bigger problem is that you need to remove any margin from the `hr` by adding a `margin:0`

Additionally you can get a more concise and understandable code by changing the `transform:translateY()` to a `top:calc()` and removing `bottom:`

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 80vw;
    height: 40vh;
    border: solid 4px #333;
}

hr {
    height: 4px; 
    margin:0;
    background-color: cadetblue;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: calc(50% - 2px);
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `transform` in css.

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 99%;
    height: 50vh;
    border: solid 4px #333;
}

hr {
    height: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: calc(50% - 5px);
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <hr>
</div>
```

In the top class define your `hr` height